# Script file loaded on partial view causing error

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a mvc.net application and on some pages I load a partial view via Ajax, returning the partial view already rendered to my script.

Everything looks fine but I am facing an issue now.
On one of my partial views, I have a java script file being loaded on the conventional way. And right after it I am using the class defined by that script

```
<script src="profile.js" />
<script >
  profile.init();
<script />
```

When this pages is returned rendered by my Ajax calls, depending on the time the profile.ja takes to be loaded, the init funcition is not being called saying that the profile is undefined.

If I run this local, the script is loaded fast enough and everything executes. But running this on a test environment where the script is loaded from cloudfront it takes more time and the function is executed before.

Is there a way that I can only execute the script after I know for sure it has been downloaded. 
Document.ready does not work cause the partial view is being loaded by Ajax

It is important to say that by some crazy stuff in our code I cannot just simply put this on my parent page or on _layout 
Any help would be appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can reference profile.js on the layout or main view, that way you'll know that profile is going to be defined when you call it in partial view.

Comment: I cannot do that on my code. I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Create a layout page and render the js files in that page, remember to use your layout in every other page you want yours scripts loaded.

Comment: I cannot do that on my code. I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily by calling `profile.init()` function in `onload` of the `script` tag. Hope this helps.

```
<script onload="profile.init()" src="profile.js"></script>
```